# Borders sticking on dynamic page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am using Twitter Bootstrap, I have a `table` which has a new row appended every time. However intermittently when I append a new `tr`, borders on the side of the page don't update correctly. See the three border lines on the left. Is this a height issue?

Browser: Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77

[image: sceenshot]

Comment: Which browser(s) is this happening in?

Comment: Do you have a code sample, or a URL or something? What do you see when you inspect those elements in chrome?

Comment: There is no node in the DOM to represent them, I will see if I can get a fiddle to replicate it.

Comment: What is the problem here exactly? I don't see anything wrong with this picture. I see no double borders, height problems, or anything like it.

Comment: On the left of the table you can see three grey borders, they intermittently stack up there when adding new rows

Comment: What's bootstrap's version?

Comment: Bootstrap is on v2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for some closure here.

The method I was using of appending items to the DOM is unwieldy especially in the backbone setting I was working in. I can't tell you why exactly this was happening other than it was outside of my control.

The correct thing to do here was to rerender the view once the data had changed.

I know this answer doesn't directly address the question but it was indeed the answer to my problem.